# WP7 Tile BackgroundImage Won't Update

Tags: windows-phone-7, background-image, live-tile

I'm trying to get the application to update the application tile, I'm basically copy pasting from the sdkTilesCS demo project (Tile Sample on this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744(v=VS.92).aspx). The application title and count always update however the tile image does not. The images path is correct, I use the same Uri object to display images within the application and the path is the same as something that works in the demo application (e.g. "blue.jpg" works in teh demo app, and after placing blue.jpg in my project and using the same uri it won't display in my app). Is there anything I'm missing, do I have to do something special to add the image to my app so that it can be used as a tile background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to mark the Build Action as 'Content' from the properties window (it's probably 'Resource' right now)

Comment: thanks! that was exactly the problem, it was set to resource, not sure why there is no mention (at least not very visibly) of that in any of the documentation